# UICollectionViewLayout: trying dequeue cell in prepareLayout causes stackOverflow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

when I try to call

`[self.collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

or

`[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ItemReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]`

I'm facing EXC_BAD_ACCESS due to stackOverflow
[image: stackTrace]

What is the proper way of getting cell view? (I need it to measure it's size)

EDIT: Interesting thing, if I comment out that code and write in output window: 
`po [self.collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]`
then there is a proper output in the console:

`<CollectionItem: 0x7f90bdc03980; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (-8.98847e+307 -8.98847e+307; 1.79769e+308 1.79769e+308); clipsToBounds = YES; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c0002213a0>>`

EDIT#2: If I do such calls in e.g. layoutAttributesForElementsInRect there is no such problems.

Comment: You're doing something in your custom cell class that causes an infinite loop.

Comment: Where are you calling these methods?

Comment: @Koen in - (void)prepareLayout

Comment: Instantiate special cell for measurement, don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`

Comment: @Cy-4AH special cell? Could you tell me some details!? Thanks

Comment: @nrudnyk just create it with alloc-init and store it reference.

Comment: That worked. Thanks.